# Double Buffering an image with GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an image (.png) stored inside of a GDI+ Image data type. Can anyone tell me how I would get image data stored in an GDI+ image variable, inside of a memory DC?

**Here is some code:**

```
Graphics graphics(hdc);
Image image(pStream);

int image_width;
int image_height;

image_width= image.GetWidth();
image_height=image.GetHeight();

graphics.DrawImage(&image, posX,posY, image_width, image_height);
```

**The objective is to be able to double buffer this GDI+ image (for animations' sake!).**

I know how to double buffer with GDI, but not with GDI+. With GDI, simply select an HBITMAP into a memory DC, however, with GDI+, the image is not in an HBITAP, but rather, in an image variable. Can anyone tell me how to get an image that is not an HBITMAP, into a memory DC? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I use for loading images from disk.

```
// BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF
HBITMAP mLoadImg(WCHAR *szFilename)
{
   HBITMAP result=NULL;

   Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename,false);
   bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &result);
   delete bitmap;
   return result;
}
```

**Edit:**
Don't use GDI+ myself, other than for a few basic features. Whenever I use images, I generally want the smallest, fastest code possible - GDI does this job better imo.

And here's the code ripped from a class that will display an image that has transparent pixels, complete with the class definition, so as to to (hopefully) avoid any ambiguity with class variables.

```
void CStaticImg::displayImage()
{
    RECT myRect;
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC screenDC, memDC;
    HBITMAP oldBmp;
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;

    GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff;

    bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    screenDC = GetDC(mHwnd);
    GetClientRect(mHwnd, &myRect);

    if (mBmp == NULL)
        FillRect(screenDC, &myRect, WHITE_BRUSH);

    else
    {
        memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mBmp);
        AlphaBlend (screenDC, 0, 0, myRect.right,myRect.bottom, memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight, bf);
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        ReleaseDC(mHwnd, screenDC);
    }
}

class CStaticImg
{
public:
    CStaticImg();
    ~CStaticImg();
    void setImg(HBITMAP img);
    HBITMAP getImgCopy();
    void attach(HWND tgt);
    void detach();
    void setBkMode(bool transparent);

protected:
    HWND mHwnd;
    HBITMAP mBmp;
    WNDPROC mOldWndProc;
    void displayImage();
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    bool isBkgTransparent;
private:
//    virtual LRESULT onPaint();
    LRESULT onCreate();
    static CStaticImg *GetObjectFromWindow(HWND hWnd);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK stWinMsgHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. I somehow missed your reply! I tried your code, and it did not work? Here is what I tried:                      DrawImage(hdc, 0, 0, (mLoadImg((WCHAR*)"myimage.png"); DrawImage is a function that double buffers an hbitmap, and draws it to the screen!

Comment: No stress mate. :) I'll fire up the compiler and check - I think the problem is in the way you pass the filename. Rather than casting a char* to a WCHAR*, you need to use the L (or possibly the TEXT) macro to ensure you're actually passing a wide string (i.e 2 bytes per char) Just gimme a few minutes, <arnoldVoice>I'll be back </arnoldVoice>

Comment: @JamesDiaz - yup, that'll be your problem. Consider that the following two have the same effect: (1) `mBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "bitmap32.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);` (2) `mBmp = mLoadImg(L"bitmap32.bmp");` **Note:** The L in front of the filename. :)

Comment: Awesome, it worked! However, I noticed that with this function, the alpha transparency in a png is not retained :(  I posted my full code above, of how I displayed a png image with alpha transparency. Hopefully someone will be able to tell me how to double buffer a png with this method, thank you.

Comment: :grins: Ahhh! That would explain the unexplained nagging feeling that I had.. You need to be a bit trickier with the way you display the bitmap. You have to use AlphaBlend. I'll update my answer to include the drawing code I use from a class I knocked-up a while back. Just a sec..

Comment: Thank you for going through so much to answer this question. I have not tried your code yet, but I'm confident it'll work! I've accepted your answer simply for the sheer effort you've put into this (that and you actually did answer my question in more way than one.) Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks for the memories of when I learnt it for the first time. Hope your experience is similarly enjoyable!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `Bitmap` class? It inherits from Image and can be used to get access to raw image data:

```
Bitmap bmp(pStream);
BitmapData bitmapData;
Rect rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
// lock area of the image for writing
bmp.LockBits(&rect, ImageLockModeWrite, PixelFormat32bppARGB, &bitmapData);
```

**Update** To get an HBITMAP something like this can be used (NOTE: I have not tested the code below):

```
   HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
   BITMAPINFO bmi;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biSize =  sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
   bmi.bmiColors = NULL;

   SetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, height,  bitmapData.Scan0, &bmi, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Win32 ;) Is there anyway to convert a Gdiplus::Bitmap into an HBITMAP?

Comment: I have posted one possible way of getting an HBITMAP to my answer. Why do you need an HBITMAP anyway?

Comment: I was hoping to double buffer the HBITMAP into a memory DC, however, I see that the HBITMAP will not retain the alpha transparency of the png image :P   I'm posting my full code in my original post, hopefully someone will be able to help me double buffer my image with the method I used to display it in the first place..